# why does cv2.imread change the pixel values?

Tags: python, image-segmentation, opencv

I recently noticed that cv2.imread changes the pixel values of images. I am doing segmentation so pixel values are important as different pixel values show different labels. I am using the code below and here my input images are masked black and white images (pixel values are only 0 and 1 as I read them in matlab to make sure.) but when I print pixel values of original_mask I see that the pixel values has been changed and goes over many different values.  Any help is greatly appreciated.
Moreover, when I print original_image.shape I see that the image is RGB which means has 3 channels (k, k, 3) and not 1 channel!!!!

```
        original_mask = cv2.imread(mask_dir + '/'+lists.iloc[i, 0] + '.png')
        print(original_mask, "original_masklllll")
        print(original_mask.shape, "original_mask")
        resized_mask = cv2.resize(original_mask, (256, 256))
        print(resized_mask.shape, "resized_mask")
        print(resized_mask, "resized_mask")
        print(resized_mask[:, :, 0], "resized_mask[:, :, 0]")
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a default second argument to `cv2.imread()` that leads to a 3-channel image. In the case of a single-channel source image, passing

```
img = cv2.imread(path, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
```

or, in the the case of an arbitrary image, passing

```
img = cv2.imread(path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
```

will result in a single channel.

Comment: Thank you for your response but it completely changes the (450,360, 1) to (450, 360). means it deletes the third dimension. How can I add manually one other dim to it to make it three dims?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `cv2.INTER_NEAREST` as input to the resize call. Otherwise you will be interpolating the vales between pixels, which is not the desired behavior. More info [here](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#void%20resize(InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20Size%20dsize,%20double%20fx,%20double%20fy,%20int%20interpolation)).

```
cv2.resize(original_mask, (256,256),interpolation=cv2.INTER_NEAREST)
```

As for the 3 channels they should all contain the same value, so you can slice off a single channel with `original_mask[...,0]`, or use `cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE` in the call to `cv2.imread`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem then. The first print statement is printing the wrong thing?

Comment: Sorry I deleted my last comment as I thought that your method works but I checked it with matlab and I faced many problematic issues. First when I use the code you suggested all values of the resized_mask become 0 or 255. It makes two labels as I want but there are problems. First, when I count the number  of none zero pixels in original_mask I see that they are equal to the number of ones and zeros in the real masked image while the 1s are changed to different numbers.

Comment: Then I resized the image with matlab and count the number of 1s and the number of 255s in the resized_image made in this program and I see that they are not the same. So, I do not know what is the reason and I am worry that this difference might change the labels and hurt the whole segmentation process.

Comment: So I am even not certain that whether this kind of comparison is right or not but I think resize function should work the same in all languages(Python or matlab)